# Guidance needed for program - Fixtures/Match

Tags: java

pretty much I'm trying to get back into full on programming in JAVA and just needed some guidence with this little project I'm working on.

Pretty much, there is a pool tournament i'm hosting and I want each player to verse each player once and once only:

I created that program(https://scontent-a-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/t1.0-9/10382869_10203343480684571_4145375306278338405_n.jpg)
That also randomizes its so ceri isn't playing the first 5 games etc.

But now what I want to do is after the games are created I want a Who won what game? kind of program..?

But the issues i'm running into are I save the Matches as a string so I cant really ask who won `Names[i]` or `Names[j]` since its saved as a string, if you get me?

I am not asking for code.. just guidance on how i could create this program, I was thinking maybe a 2d array or some sort???

Comment: Also I know the use of methods should be used but Ive been out of programming a long time and i seriously struggled to make it with methods.

Comment: how about a database?  then you can persist the values and create queries and reports later.

Comment: not a bad idea, problem is during my University time(first year) I was never taught DB with java @Randy

Comment: That's not a problem, unless your brain is right now incapable of learning new things of course.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints to start it all of.

- Create a class Player.
- Create a class Game which takes two Players and can hold a (final) score.
- Instantiate one Player for each player
- Instantiate one Game for each pair of players (just iterate over them)
- Randomise all of the Games
- For each Game prompt for, and enter, the final result.